# How to play rtmp live stream in web browser?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, video.js

I am trying the rtmp url in video js player.But it was not working .

In video js we have to give the type(application/x-mpegURL | video/mp4) in the source.

```
    <video id="wiPlayer" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
               controls codecs="avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2" preload="auto" width="1200" height="400" poster="<?=$post->screenShotUrl?>" 
                data-setup='{"aspectRatio":"640:320", "autoplay": true, "controlBar": {"fullscreenToggle": true, "progressControl": true}}'>
 <p class="vjs-no-js">We're sorry, but your browser doesn't support Video</p>
 </video>
```

the js code is

```
player = videojs('wiPlayer');
        player.src({
                src: stream_url,
                type: mPlayerType,// "video/mp4",//application/x-mpegURL
                useCueTags: true
                 });
        window.onOrientation(player, 'wiPlayer');
        player.play();
```

for me the url is like :

```
rtmp://vid-11239002.pull.usnecenter.broadcastapp.agora.cn/live/public1265537
```

How can i play this kind of live stream urls with video js? or do we have any other solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The type for RTMP is `rtmp/mp4` or `rtmp/flv`. This will only work on a browser that has Flash.